# Querying for distant relations

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm working on modeling some relational data in an app. I'm wondering mostly about how to deal with distant relations in SQL, though for context it's a Ruby app and I'm using Sequel as an ORM.

One example relationship looks like this:

```
alphas one-to-many bravos
bravos many-to-one charlies
charlies one-to-many deltas
deltas one-to-many echoes
```

So, using the ORM and doing the work in Ruby I might naively query for all Echoes related to an Alpha like so:

```ruby
a = Alpha.where id: 1
echoes = []
a.bravos.each do |bravo|
  bravo.charlie.deltas.each do |delta|
    echoes << delta.echoes
  end
end
echoes.flatten
```

This works but fails to take advantage of the database and rather does most of the work in the application layer. Expressing the same idea in ugly psuedo-sql subqueries it would look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM echoes WHERE delta_id IN
  SELECT delta_id FROM charlies WHERE charlie_id IN
    SELECT charlie_id FROM bravos WHERE bravo_id IN
      SELECT id FROM bravos WHERE alpha_id = 1
```

This is essentially the same brute force approach, it seems like there must be a better way.

So my question is:

1. What is a better way to write a query for a distant relationship like this?
2. Is there a change to the schema design that should be made to represent this kind of distant relation?

It occurs to me that I could create an `alpha_id` column on `echoes` and use this to query directly, I then would rely on the application to always update that column if the intermediate relations change. That seems to me like a bad idea, but it would certainly make for more efficient queries in this case.

I'd love to hear from some SQL pros, what do you do when you have distantly related data that you need to query frequently?

Comment: I would have a look at this doc on [Sequel Queries](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html). You could even just execute your raw SQL like `DB["SELECT * FROM echos INNER JOIN deltas ON delta.id = echos.delta_id INNER JOIN charlies ON charlies.id = deltas.charlie_id INNER JOIN bravos ON bravos.id = charlies.bravo_id INNER JOIN alphas on alphas.id = bravos.alpha_id WHERE alphas.id = ?", 1]`